# Value of Expressions in sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm studying for my finals and I came across these questions:

> Determine the value of the following expressions:
>
> a) $|\{a,b,c,d,e\}\cap \{c,d,e,f,g\}|=$
>
> b) $|\{(a,b,c,d,e\}\cap\{c,d,e,f,g\})\cup\{l,c,e,g,i\}|=$
>
> c) $|\{\ldots,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3\} \cap \{-1,0,1,2,3,4,\ldots\}|=$

Is it correct to say that these are the answers for the following:

a) 3  (c,d,e)

b) 7  (d,e,c,l,i,e,g)

c) 5  (-1,0,1,2,3)

because this | | notation means the number of elements..

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: In $b$ you have to counted $e$ only once otherwise you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For b you have counted e twice.  But you obviously are thinking about it correctly.